# macOS - Convert ELF shared object file to MACHO

Tags: macos, shared-libraries, static-libraries, elf, mach-o

I have a `.so` library file that I need to reference from C under macOS. `file` gives:

```
ELF 32-bit MSB shared object, MIPS, MIPS-II version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

How can I munge the contents of the library so that it can be linked under macOS?

I have tried: objconv, objdump, readelf, dwarfdump - but the flags and output are unintelligible to me so far.

The joint furthest I get is with gobjcopy, but then:

```
gobjcopy: Unable to change endianness of input file(s)
```

Also, objconv throws:

```
Error 2022: Cannot convert executable file
```

Do I need to deconstruct the `.so` into object files first, convert each and then bundle them back up to together?

Thanks for all help.

Comment: If the library truly was built for MIPS, you're not gonna get it to run on x86_64 - you'll have to read and understand the disassembly, and basically rewrite the entire library yourself.

Comment: @Siguza I am a bit unfamiliar with MIPS - could I compile on such a system?

Comment: MIPS is a processor family, like x86 or ARM. And no, macOS only runs on x86(_64).